# Change title text color of a specific segment in UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I change the text color of just one specific segment of a UISegmentedControl? I want to keep them all normal, except for a specific segment which should be a different color, whether it is selected or not.

Answer (score 4):

```
@IBDesignable
    class DesignableSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl{
    }
    extension UISegmentedControl{
        @IBInspectable
        var textColor: UIColor{
            get {
                return self.textColor
            }
            set {
                let unselectedAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: newValue,
                                            NSAttributedString.Key.font:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)]
                self.setTitleTextAttributes(unselectedAttributes, for: .normal)
                self.setTitleTextAttributes(unselectedAttributes, for: .selected)
            }
        }
    }
```

Just change you segment control's class name as shown below:

[change class name]:
[image]

[change text color]:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't achieve what the OP is asking, which is to change the font attributes of just one section "whether it is selected or not".

Answer (score 2):

**for swift 5**:

```
segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes( [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
```

Comment: What is `yourSegment`?

Comment: @adamjansch it would be a `UISegmentedControl` object in the UIkit

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as already given, which doesn't solve what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built-in way; as you've probably figured out, `setTitleTextAttributes` applies to all the segments. You would have to draw your text as an image and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Swift 4.1**

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```

**Swift 3.1**

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red as Any], for: .selected)
```

**For Earlier Swift Version:**

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```

Comment: This will set the title text attributes for all of the segments. I just want to change one individual segment's text color.

Comment: This will also set the title text attributes for all of the segments for *all subsequent* UISegmentedControls instantiated after this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own segmented control for customisation.

1. Add two buttons with same UI as segmented control.
2. Round the corners.
3. On click make the background colour according to your need and clear back ground of other and make it unselected.

In this way there is large scope for customisation.
Also there are many custom segmented control are available at GitHub.
You can try this

https://github.com/gmarm/BetterSegmentedControl

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21600639)

Comment: Please check again.